# Concatenate multi-column text files containing numbers & nan

Tags: python, text, append, concatenation

I have a folder named `17307` which contains some `.ismr` files (essentially just CSV files) named like

```
SEPT307A.17_.ismr, 
SEPT307B.17_.ismr, 
SEPT307C.17_.ismr,.... upto SEPT307X.17_.ismr.
```

I want to concatenate all these into a single text file using Python. I tried:

```
st = 'path/to/folder'
a = input('Enter first part of file') #i.e. SEPT307 in file name
alph = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X']
yr = input('enter the year')
last = '_.ismr'
for letter in alph:
    st1 = st + "a" + alph + "." + "yr" + last
    fp = open(st1, "r")
    data=np.append(data, np.fromfile(fp, dtype=list))
```

i.e. I am trying to put everything into data and later copy data to a separate text file.
However I am getting this error:

> TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly

Can anyone kindly suggest some way for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the error coming from this line:

```
st1 = st + "a" + alph + "." + "yr" + last
```

Where `alph` is the full list of your alphabet. It should be:

```
st1 = st + "a" + letter + "." + "yr" + last
```

The issue is that you are trying to concatenate a `list` with a `str`.